# How to search through struct data using UISearchBar swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, xcode, struct, uisearchbar, swift4.2

I have struct datatype which is use for decoding data

```
struct OtherCountry : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let dial_code : String
    let code : String

}

struct FrequentCountry:Decodable{
    let name : String
    let dial_code : String
    let code : String
}
```

I want to search based on name & code  and this is stored in array of type struct

```
    var OtherDataCountry = [OtherCountry]()
    var FrequentDataCountry = [FrequentCountry]()
```

I have also implemented search function that looks something like this

```
func searchBar(searchText: String) {
        searchCountry1 = OtherDataCountry.filter({ (OtherCountry) -> Bool in
            return OtherCountry.name.range(of: searchText , options:[.caseInsensitive]) != nil

        searchActive = !searchCountry1.isEmpty

            self.mTableView.reloadData()
        }

        )}
}
```

can anyone help me to convert that struct data to String array , that would be helpful because i can search through array and use that result to show entire data .

Thank You for Help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code

```
func searchBar(searchText: String) {
            searchCountry1 = OtherDataCountry.filter {
                $0.name.range(of: searchText , options:[.caseInsensitive]) != nil
    }.map {$0.name}

            searchActive = !searchCountry1.isEmpty

                self.mTableView.reloadData()
            }

            )
    }
```

searchCountry1 will be an array after map containing the name value

Comment: it did work but i had to make few changes , i had to use "func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) " inside this function i entered the code without the map.